# List all injective relations between two sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$A=\{1,2\}$

$B=\{2,3\}$

List all injective relations $F: A \rightarrow B$

This is what I came up with:

$$F_1(1)=2$$ $$F_1(2)=3$$
$$F_2(1)=3$$ $$F_2(2)=2$$

Is that all? It seems to me that I'm missing something here. Can you also have an element in $A$ that doesn't translate to any element in $B$?

Comment: You listed all injective *functions* (which are also relations, but not all)

Comment: So, you can have, for example, $F_3:A\rightarrow B$, such that $F_3(1)=2$, and $ \exists!F_3(2)$?

Comment: Also, I saw this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937802/how-many-injective-relations-exist-between-a-and-b, and it seems that if |A|=|B|, and |A|=2, so there should be 2!=2 injective relations $F:A\rightarrow B$

Comment: So, I listed 2  of them, so that's all of them. How come Hagen von Eitzen says there are more?

Comment: How is an *injective relation* defined? Does e.g. $\{(1,2),\,(1,3)\}$ satisfy that definition?

Comment: This I don't know. Maybe someone could clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

If what we want is the total amount of *relations* then there's a total of 9, considering that for any element $a \in A$, $F(a)$ might not exists, and $F(a)=\{ 2,3\}$ is also valid.

If we are talking about *functions* $F: A\rightarrow B$, there are only two, mentioned in the original question. Since there is an added restriction, that $\forall a \in A, \exists! b \hookrightarrow F(a)=b$.

Edit: disclaimer

Okay, I think this is logical since our proffessor said that there should be 9 relations in total, so I think that's the only way to come up with them. I'm not marking this answer as correct, though, since I'm still learning on this topic. It'd be helpful if someone with more experience could verify this.